# How to make Microsoft XmlHttpRequest honor cache control directive

Tags: xmlhttprequest, msxml, cache-control

i'm issuing a request using MSXML's [XmlHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760305(v=vs.85).aspx) object:

```
IXMLHttpRequest http = new XmlHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", "http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stat/fx-xml.xml", False, "", "");
http.send();
```

And the `send` succeeds, and i get my xml data.

Except that `XmlHttpRequest` didn't actually hit the network (i can see there no actual http request issued). And Process Monitor shows the file is actually being served from my cache:

[image]

So i want to instruct the `XmlHttpRequest` user agent that any cached content older than 0 seconds is too old. The [standards way](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to do this is to add a request header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

to the send request:

```
http = new XmlHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", "http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stat/fx-xml.xml", False, "", "");
http.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
http.send();
```

And the `send` succeeds, and i get my xml data.

Except that `XmlHttpRequest` didn't actually hit the network (i can see there no actual http request issued). And Process Monitor shows the file is actually being served from my cache.

So what is wrong? Is `max-age` not doing what i think it does?

From [RFC 2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol, Part 14: Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3):

> Other directives allow a user agent to
>   modify the basic expiration mechanism.
>   These directives MAY be specified on a
>   request:
>
> max-age
>   Indicates that the client is
>   willing to accept a response whose age
>   is no greater than the specified time
>   in seconds. Unless max- stale
>   directive is also included, the client
>   is not willing to accept a stale
>   response.

Which exactly what i want.

Is `Cache-Control: max-age=0` not exactly what i want, or is MSXML's `XmlHttpRequest` object buggy?

### Update One

This is the MSXML `XmlHttpRequest` COM object:

- CLSID: {88d96a0a-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5}
- ProgID: Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0

### Update Two

The `max-age` directive is added by the client for all cache's to adhere to. From RFC:

> The Cache-Control general-header field
>   is used to specify directives that
>   **MUST be obeyed by all caching
>   mechanisms along the request/response
>   chain**. The directives specify behavior
>   intended to prevent caches from
>   adversely interfering with the request
>   or response. These directives
>   typically override the default caching
>   algorithms. Cache directives are
>   unidirectional in that the presence of
>   a directive in a request does not
>   imply that the same directive is to be
>   given in the response.

Max-age is not for the server; it makes no sense for a server. It is intended for all caching systems **between** the user and the server.

### Update Three

From [W3C XmlHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method):

> If the user agent implements a HTTP cache it *should* respect
>   `Cache-Control` request headers set by
>   the [`setRequestHeader()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader) (e.g.,
>   `Cache-Control: no-cache` bypasses the
>   cache). It *must not* send `Cache-Control`
>   or `Pragma` request headers
>   automatically unless the end user
>   explicitly requests such behavior
>   (e.g. by reloading the page).

Following their *example*, i tried using the `no-cache` directive:

```
http = new XmlHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", "http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stat/fx-xml.xml", False, "", "");
http.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
http.send();
```

And the `XmlHttpRequest` client still services requests completely from the cache, without querying the server at all.

The W3C says that if there is a cache, it must honor `Cache-Control` if it is set through `setRequestHeader`. Microsoft's XmlHttpRequest doesn't seem to honor that requirement.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately the `XMLHttpRequest` object was designed this way, because it is based on WinInet. Also, it is not recommend to be used from the server side. You should use [`ServerXMLHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which has the same functionality, but depends on [`WinHTTP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead. See the [FAQ](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290761) for more information. A description from the `ServerXMLHttp` documentation states that:

> The HTTP client stack offers longer
>   uptimes. WinInet features that are not
>   critical for server applications, such
>   as URL caching, auto-discovery of
>   proxy servers, HTTP/1.1 chunking,
>   offline support, and support for
>   Gopher and FTP protocols are not
>   included in the new HTTP subset.

This means that rather than using [**XmlHttpRequest**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
IXMLHTTPRequest http = CreateComObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");     http.open("GET", "http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stat/fx-xml.xml", False, "", "");
http.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
http.send();
```

you can use [**ServerXmlHttpRequest**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278(v=VS.85).aspx):

```
IXMLHTTPRequest http = CreateComObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP");
http.open("GET", "http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stat/fx-xml.xml", False, "", "");
http.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
http.send();
```

or [WinHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383979(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
IWinHttpRequest http = CreateComObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
http.open("GET", "http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stat/fx-xml.xml", False, "", "");
http.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
http.send();
```

Comment: You're right. i just tested this using `ServerXmlHttpRequest` and `WinHttpRequest`. Those two do no caching whatsoever. While `XmlHttpRequest` does perform caching - it doesn't follow the W3C standards for that requests to bypass that cache. +1 and Accepted.

Comment: I tried using both WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 and MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0, but It didn't work for me... can that be a server setting or something else?

Comment: @thiagoleite What didn't work for you? What OS are you using? Did you receive and error?

Comment: @Garret Its a webfarm of 5 Windows Server 2008 64, IIS7. I created a proxy in ASP Classic to consume a rss feed, it just makes a request and parse the xml. I get no error at all, just that when i make an update in the feed, my proxy won't get the updated information. I read somewhere that ServerXmlHttpRequest has a bug regarding caching, but cant remember where i read it.

Comment: @thiagoleite Hi, this may require a new question in order to solicit more feed back. It may well be a bug, but I would also like to see more details, including snippets of the code you are using.

Answer (score 8):

I found that using `If-None-Match` header, specifing a value that does not match the `ETag` of the last request will work.

Eg:

```
req.open("GET", url, false);
req.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match", "\"doesnt-match-anything\"");
req.send();
```

This might or might not require that the responses include an `ETag`. (I only tried it with a service that includes an `ETag` value in each response.)

Answer (score 1):

Could you append a bogus parameter on the end of your URI that changes with each request?

```
http.open("GET", "http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stat/fx-xml.xml?requestID=42", False, "", "");
```

Comment: Problem with that is that it doesn't bypass the cache, it simply issues a separate request; filling my cache with thousands copies of the same resource. i'd like to know how to follow the cache rules.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for a keep-alive session and it works great.
The trick is to use the header "If-Modified-Since" with a value newer that the one cached by the browser.

```
g_AjaxObj.onreadystatechange = function() { if(g_AjaxObj.readyState === 4) { AjaxOnComplete_("KeepAlive"); }};
g_AjaxObj.open('GET', URL, true);
g_AjaxObj.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", new Date().toUTCString());
g_AjaxObj.send(null);
```

Comment: `If-Modified-Since` the opposite of what i want. Adding `If-Modified-Since` allows the server to return `304 Not Modified`. i want to bypass the cache - not work with it

Answer (score 1):

My quick and dirty workaround at a standard Windows client was
- **Internet Options**
- General
- **Browsing history Settings**
- Check for newer Versions of stored pages:
**tickle** "(x) Every time I visit the Webpage"
Now my *Msxml2.XMLHTTP.x.0* Object don't use the Cache anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

This header is for the server, and as the browser doesnt event do any request, its useless.

An easy trick is to load the page like this :

```
http.open("GET", "http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stat/fx-xml.xml?"+Math.random(), False, "", "");
```

Comment: Problem with that is that it doesn't bypass the cache, it simply issues a separate request; filling my cache with thousands copies of the same resource. i'd like to know how to follow the cache rules.

Comment: the server only sends an 'etag' header in the response, so the cache is pure client-side ? you can force IE not to cache in options->internet options->temp files->always check new file

Comment: This isn't from ie, it's a native application using `XmlHttpRequest`.

Comment: IMHO native xmlhttpapps use the IE cache settings. as they use IE proxy

Comment: i cannot be changing the cache policy on every machine that runs my application (that's just not being a good program). And besides, the W3C dictates that if i specify a `Cache-Control` header in my request, the XmlHttpRequest implementation is supposed to honor it.

Answer (score 0):

For old msxml library, I use random generated value for uri adress eg :

http://youlink?mysession=random_number

wojtek

Comment: Downside of that is that you flood the cache with multiple copies of the same content. It might be a hack around buggy http agents - but a real solution is to work *with* caching mechanisms, rather than against them.

Answer (score 0):

> Downside of that is that you flood the cache with multiple copies of
>   the same content. It might be a hack around buggy http agents - but a
>   real solution is to work with caching mechanisms, rather than against
>   them. –

I agree that this is not ideal and not really a solution, but Mozilla actually recommend this as a workaround, so I figure it mustn't be too terrible - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Besides, I was tearing my hair out trying to solve this.  I've had to rely on my users to clear their browser (which they keep forgetting to do).  So this is a godsend for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try sending **'cache-control: private'** as a header. This worked for me:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", 'http://myurl.com' , false); 

request.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "private");
```

I'm writing a HTML & Javascript app for Windows 8 where and both no-cache and max-age are ignored. For me the above works just fine.

I wasn't familiar with the header so did a little digging on cache-control: private...

```
Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache, such as a proxy server.
```

From [What is Cache-Control: private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908766/what-is-cache-control-private)
and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

So, basically, this will never create a cache entry and therefore doesn't add cache entries that we know are superfluous, as with a 'cache-buster' random number parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy. This SO thread came closest to providing an answer. Unfortunately during testing none of them actually worked for me. The only solution I found which tested to work correctly was setting:

Header Pragma: no-cache

I hope it saves others with IE headaches.

BTW this is StackOverflow thread is great to shed light on the difference between Pragma and Cache-control:
[Difference between Pragma and Cache-control headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers)