# What is Cache-Control: private?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

When I visit [chesseng.herokuapp.com](http://chesseng.herokuapp.com) I get a response header that looks like

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Tue, 16 Oct 2012 06:37:53 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 16 Oct 2012 03:13:38 GMT
Status:200 OK
transfer-encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Rack-Cache:miss
```

and then I refresh the page and get

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Tue, 16 Oct 2012 06:20:49 GMT
Status:304 Not Modified
X-Rack-Cache:miss
```

so it seems like caching is working. If that works for caching then what is the point of ***Expires*** and **Cache-Control:max-age**. To add to confusion, when I test the page at [https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) it tells me to "Leverage browser caching".

Comment: check this diagram https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925190/3748498

Answer (score 104, accepted):

To answer your question about why caching is working, even though the web-server did **not** either:

- **Expires:** `[a date]`
- **Cache-Control:** max-age=`[seconds]`

Yes, the server did kindly ask any *intermediate* proxies to not cache the contents (i.e. the item should only be cached in a *private* cache, i.e. only on your own local machine):

- **Cache-Control:** `private`

But the server forgot to include any sort of caching hints:

- they forgot to include **Expires** (so the browser knows to use the cached copy until that date)
- they forgot to include **Max-Age** (so the browser knows how long the cached item is good for)
- they forgot to include **E-Tag** (so the browser can do a conditional request)

But they **did** include a  **Last-Modified** date in the response:

- **Last-Modified:** `Tue, 16 Oct 2012 03:13:38 GMT`

Now, because the browser knows the date the file was modified, it can perform a **[conditional request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Conditional_requests)**. It will ask the server for the file, but instruct the server to only send the file if it has been modified since 2012/10/16 3:13:38:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 03:13:38 GMT
```

The server receives the request, realizes that the client has the most recent version already. Rather than sending the client `200 OK`, followed by the contents of the page, it instead tells you that your cached version is good:

```
304 Not Modified
```

Your browser *did* have to suffer the round-trip delay of sending a request to the server, and waiting for the response, but it did save having to re-download the static content.

### Why **Max-Age**? Why **Expires**?

Because **Last-Modified** sucks.

Not everything on the server **has** a date associated with it. If I'm building a page on the fly, there is no date associated with it - it's **now**. But I'm perfectly willing to let the user cache the homepage for 15 seconds:

```
200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=15
```

If the user hammers <kbd>F5</kbd>, they'll keep getting the cached version for 15 seconds. If it's a corporate proxy, then all 67,198 users hitting the same page in the same 15-second window will all get the same contents - all served from close cache. Performance win for everyone.

The virtue of adding `Cache-Control: max-age` is that the browser doesn't even **have** to perform a "conditional" request.

- if you specified only `Last-Modified`, the browser has to perform a `If-Modified-Since` request, and watch for a `304 Not Modified` response
- if you specified `max-age`, the browser won't even **have** to suffer the network round-trip; the content will come right out of the caches.

### The difference between "Cache-Control: max-age" and "Expires"

`Expires` is a legacy (c. 1998) equivalent of the modern `Cache-Control: max-age` header:

- `Expires`: you specify a date *(yuck)*
- `max-age`: you specify seconds *(goodness)*
- And if **both** are specified, then the browser uses `max-age`:

  ```
    200 OK
    Cache-Control: max-age=60
    Expires: 20180403T192837
  ```

Any web-site written after 1998 should not use `Expires` anymore, and instead use `max-age`.

### What is ETag?

**ETag** is similar to **Last-Modified**, except that it doesn't have to be a date - it just has to be a ***`something`***.

If I'm pulling a list of products out of a database, the server can send the last `rowversion` as an ETag, rather than a date:

```
200 OK
ETag: "247986"
```

My ETag can be the SHA1 hash of a static resource (e.g. image, js, css, font), or of the cached rendered page (i.e. this is what the Mozilla MDN wiki does; they hash the final markup):

```
200 OK
ETag: "33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4"
```

And exactly like in the case of a conditional request based on **Last-Modified**:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 03:13:38 GMT

304 Not Modified
```

I can perform a *conditional request* based on the ETag:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
If-None-Match: "33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4"

304 Not Modified
```

An `ETag` is superior to `Last-Modified` because it works for things besides *files*, or things that have a notion of *date*. It just *is*

Comment: Awesome! I placed a bounty for this answer. What happens if `cache-control` doesn't exist? And you only have Etag? Doesn't it still need to make a 'conditional request' against the server? The behavior I'm seeing when I'm offline is that it just returns from cache. But when it's offline it can't make that conditional request. So does that mean if it will cache indefinitely if you stay offline? I've already asked this question in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086297/does-not-setting-cache-control-automatically-enable-caching-even-without-conditi). Can you take a look?

Answer (score 176):

```
Cache-Control: private
```

> Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache, such as a proxy server.

From [RFC2616 section 14.9.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: So can you explain why the response after the refresh has Status:304 Not Modified

Comment: Because it was cached by your browser. You are the single user that response was intended for.

Comment: So isn't having each single user cache it effectively the same as  Expires or Cache-Control:max-age.

Comment: No, it is not because `Cache-Control:private` only states that shared caches (such as proxy caches) should not cache the response.

Comment: I see that even when this header is present, Chrome will cache an item between two profiles in the same browser. So I assume that "single user" really means "single computer".

Comment: @Trejkaz No, it really means a single user. A user is a account which has its own home directory in which the cache resides. Those profiles which are owned by the same user may share their cache. As you have found. But two profiles on the same computer if owned by different users must not share their cache, unless that cache is treated as a shared cache.

Comment: Ah, so it's per-user-at-the-OS-level. Yeah, the reason I'm wondering is because of an apparent information leak between Chrome's incognito windows and the non-incognito ones, which uses the cache to do it.

Comment: What would be the difference with proxy-revalidate?

Comment: @didibus `proxy-revalidate` requires that proxies always revalidate on each access. Where as `private` prevents the proxy from caching.

Answer (score 22):

RFC 2616, [section 14.9.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1):

> Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache...A private (non-shared) cache MAY cache the response.

---

Browsers could use this information. Of course, the current "user" may mean many things: OS user, a browser user (e.g. Chrome's profiles), etc. It's not specified.

For me, **a more concrete example** of `Cache-Control: private` is that proxy servers (which typically have many users) won't cache it. It is meant for the end user, and no one else.

---

FYI, the RFC makes clear that this does not provide security. It is about showing the correct content, not securing content.

> This usage of the word private only controls where the response may be cached, and cannot ensure the privacy of the message content.

Comment: **A private (non-shared) cache MAY cache the response.** This part is key. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Expires entity-header field gives the date/time after which the response is considered stale.The Cache-control:maxage field gives the age value (in seconds)  bigger than which response is consider stale.

Althought above header field give a mechanism  to client to decide whether to send request to the server. In some condition, the client send a request to sever and the age value of response is bigger then the maxage value  ,dose it means server needs to send the resource to client? Maybe the resource never changed.

In order to resolve this problem, HTTP1.1 gives last-modifided head. The server gives the last modified date of the response to client. When the client need  this resource, it will send If-Modified-Since head field to server. If this date is before the modified date of the resouce, the server will sends the resource to client and gives 200 code.Otherwise,it will returns 304 code to client and this means client can use the resource it cached.