# Codeigniter user session showing same for different users

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

The Project is running on CodeIgniter (v 3.1.9).

from the Login page

When two different users (A and B) try to login from two different systems at same time, both users gets the same session values.

If A log's in first(1 or 2 seconds), then the user B gets the session of A's,
After a reload the correct session are restored.

This happens in the opposite way also.

So both the users gets the same dashboard the first time, which is pretty bad,

this only happenes when we try to login with 2 users at the same time.

If anybody has any pointers that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same thing happened when I was using server side cache. Please check it if you are using.

Comment: Thanks @AyazShah, why didn't i think of that, let me see if that solves the problem for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908766/what-is-cache-control-private

Comment: @popeye so that means we need to use the 'Cache-Control: private', let mecheck how its in the server. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO After Long sleepless nights i figured out what was causing the issue, and it is a funny one.

Posting this answer so that if anybody comes looking for this.

So my codeigniter project was loaded in a sub folder of a domain, and that was the issue, somehow the codeigniter sessions gets mixed up when using the subfolder, when i moved it to another domain and everything worked perfectly.

just so you know i did add the required .htaccess for this folder.
@AyazShah @popeye thanks..