# Laravel remove header values from API response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel App Version 5.6 
i wish to remove the value private from the Cache-Control Header which is presented in the API response

[image]

i have a middleware that is adding the "no-cache" and "no-store" values

```
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store');
    return $response;
```

is it possible to do it in the same Middleware or any other work around

EDIT1 : 
in PHP.ini i have left the value "session.cache_limiter" empty, made sure .htacess is not appending headers and changed my middleware to do the following

```
$response->headers->remove('Cache-Control');
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store');
```

still getting the private value in the header.

Comment: wait, what's the problem with that private value?

Comment: uh oh... can you check other middlewares?

Comment: yeah i did none of them is adding the private value

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908766/what-is-cache-control-private

Comment: @HilAyPatel that was a nice description however i don't want to know what it means but rather i wish to remove the private value! using a laravel method or tooling ........

Comment: I think it's set by default by `symfony\http-foundation\ResponseHeaderBag`. It looks like it want to set `private` or `public`, you can't remove it. Unless you edit the `computeCacheControlValue()` function

Comment: @Smankusors absolutely correct if i follow the logic unless i append s-maxage to cache-control it will add private by default it's a bit weird but still the way it works please write this as an answer so i can mark it correct thanks a lot dude

Comment: wait, you previously only want no-cache and no-store... well to be honest, the `private` value itself looks okay for me, instead adding weird `s-maxage` :D

Comment: @Smankusors yeah but changing Symphony is not acceptable setting `s-maxage=0` is kind of acceptable while I know this would practically do the same job as `private`
this is more acceptable apparently.