# Remove any Header in PHP - Laravel API response

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I searched for a way to remove headers in API response, but the already answered questions are talking about an specific Header and not any of them, like: [Laravel remove header values from API response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016419/laravel-remove-header-values-from-api-response)

In my scenario the APIs are called from a device which doesn't care about `Date` , `Host` , `X-Powered-By`, ... and so many other headers in API resposne. in my case response size is so important, my data is `100B` but my `Headers` are about `350B`!!

so my question is how to edit or remove Headers in Laravel or PHP, is there anyway to modify these Headers and just keep the really needed ones.

Comment: Have you tried to investigate Response file itself?

Comment: @SomeDev what do you mean exactly? if you mean the way response is created in laravel, its common way `response()->json`

Comment: I mean, dig into Laravel response files, how laravel generate responses. There maybe ways you customize them for your personal use

Comment: @SomeDev thats exactly my question! is there anyway? if so how is that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483781/http-response-with-no-http-header

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I think it is against specification too. What are you doing that even bytes are important for? Maybe there are other ways that let you not touch standart response

Comment: device uses 2G internet connection. so reducing response size may help to make connection faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web server (Nginx or Apache) is probably adding a few headers as well, not sure if you can disable all of them though. You need to edit the server/site config file for your web server to accomplish this since they are added after the php script has been executed.