# http.responseText response seems outdated from cache

Tags: excel, vba, http, plumber, serverxmlhttp

I host a local server on my pc with Plumber from R.
Next I call the server from Excel VBA.
If I use `Debug.Print getHTTP(myurl)`  I do receive an up-to-date response.
If I use `Debug.Print (http.responseText)` I do receive an outdated response. I assume from cache.

If I call myurl with browser Chrome the response is up-to-date.

Please see code below.

Any idea what can be the cause of the outdated response from `Debug.Print (http.responseText)` ?

Thanks a lot!

```
    Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
      With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
      End With
    End Function
    
    
    Sub APItest()
    
    Dim myurl As String
    Dim JSON As Object
    Dim http As Object
    
    myurl = "http://127.0.0.1:1234/my_local_api_server"
    
    Debug.Print getHTTP(myurl) 'this line gives actual output 
    
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    http.Open "GET", myurl, False
    
    http.send
    
    Debug.Print (http.responseText) 'this line gives outdated output from cache

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using Cache-Control headers on the HTTP response?

Comment: @ Tim Williams Thanks, you pinpointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

See answer below:

[How to make Microsoft XmlHttpRequest honor cache control directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235464/how-to-make-microsoft-xmlhttprequest-honor-cache-control-directive)

The function in my question getHTTP uses MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 which does not has the cashing issue.